# R: Can I pass the weight parameter into the params = list() in LightGBM

Tags: r, lightgbm

Recently, I am learning the LightGBM package and want to tune the parameters of it.

I want to try all the parameters which can be tuned in the LightGBM.

One question is: when I build the model using the function: `lightgbm(data, label = NULL, weight = NULL, params = list(), nrounds = 10, verbose = 1)`, can I put the `weight` and `nrounds` and `many other parameters` into a list object and feed to the `params` argument?

The following code is what I used:

```
# input data for lgb.Dataset() 
data_lgb <- lgb.Dataset(
  data = X_tr,
  label = y_tr
)

# can I put all parameters to be tuned into this list?
params_list <- list(weight = NULL, nrounds = 20, verbose = 1, learning_rate = 0.1)

# build lightgbm model using only: data_lgb and params_list
lgb_model <- lightgbm(data_lgb, params = params_list)
```

Can I do this using the above code?

I ask because I have a large training data set (2 million rows and 700 features). If I put the lgb.Dataset() into the lightgbm such as `lightgbm(data = lgb.Dataset(data = X_tr,label = y_tr), params = params_list)`, then It takes time for multiple model building. Therefore, I first get the dataset used for lightgbm and for each model, the dataset is constant, what I did can only focus on the different parameters.

However, I am not sure, in total, how many parameters can be put into the `params_list`? Such as can the `weight` parameter be in the `params_list`? When I look the help `?lightgbm`, I notice that the `weight` parameter and many other `parameters` are out side of the `params_list`.

Can you help me figure out: in total which parameters can be put into the `params_list`? That is the final model is built only using the `data` argument and `params` argument (other parameters are put into the params list object) as shown above, is that feasible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lightgbm` has many params which you can tune. Please read the documentation.

I am pasting some part from one of my model script which shows the process. Should be a good hint for you.

```
nthread <- as.integer(future::availableCores())
seed <- 1000
EARLY_STOPPING <- 50
nrounds <- 1000
param <- list(objective = "regression"
                    metric = "rmse",
                    max_depth = 3,
                    num_leaves = 5,
                    learning_rate = 0.1,
                    nthread = nthread,
                    bagging_fraction = 0.7,
                    feature_fraction = 0.7,
                    bagging_freq = 5,
                    bagging_seed = seed,
                    verbosity = -1,
                    min_data_in_leaf = 5)


dtrain <- lgb.Dataset(data = as.matrix(train_X),
                    label = train_y)

dval <- lgb.Dataset(data = as.matrix(val_X),
                    label = val_y)
valids <- list(val = dval)
bst <- lgb.train(param,
                 data = dtrain,
                 nrounds = nrounds,
                 data_random_seed = seed,
                 early_stopping_rounds = EARLY_STOPPING,
                 valids = valids)
```